# Meaning of Quote from Plutarch, Life of Pyrrhus

Tags: meaning

In the Life of Pyrrhus, Plutarch writes:

> "I know not what kind of barbarians these may be; but the disposition of this army that I see has nothing of barbarism in it."

The context being King Pyrrhus is invading Italy, and apparently Greeks called all other nations barbarians.

By "nothing of barbarism in it" is Pyrrrhus praising the army by saying that they look brave and ordered? Would a correct alternate wording be:

> "We call these guys barbarians, but this army doesn't look very barbaric to me"

Comment: Greek and Roman and (in the case of Plutarch) Greek Roman historians tended to have a very low opinion of barbarian armies. Many of these forces were essentially mobs or hordes without discernible discipline or well-defined subunits. Whether victorious or defeated they tended to plunge into disarray almost at once when the field was won or lost, and they usually displayed little strategy and orderliness. So in seeing a force that showed good order and a strategic disposition of its forces, the Greek/Roman observer was struck by how little it resembled other barbarian armies he had seen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your intuition is correct. Here's my 'plain English' translation of the passage:

"I don't know where these barbarians [i.e., foreigners] might come from, but the way the army is organized is not at all barbaric [i.e., foreign and, implicitly, inferior]."

If you give me a section citation, I can check the original Greek to see if the translation you have is accurate.